# how to create own auto-configuration in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to create my own auto-configuration in spring boot.
So I created a library and a class `CustomTemplateClient`.

```
public class CustomTemplateClient{
    public <T> T get(URI url, Class<T> responseType) throws RestClientException {
        // do something
    }
```

I created a AutoConfiguration class `CustomClientAutoConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
public class CustomClientAutoConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public CustomTemplateClient customTemplateClient() {
        return new CustomTemplateClient();
    }
}
```

I created `spring.factories` file under `resources/META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
  com.example.http.config.CustomClientAutoConfiguration
```

The pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>example-starter-http-client</artifactId>

    <name>example-starter-http-client</name>

     <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.1.2</surefire-plugin.version>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <spring.boot.bom.version>3.1.3</spring.boot.bom.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I have the build the jar and the jar I am using as a dependency in some other projects.

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    private static final String FAKE_STORE = "https://fakestoreapi.com";
    private final CustomTemplateClient customTemplateClient;

    public ProductController(CustomTemplateClient customTemplateClient) {
        this.customTemplateClient = customTemplateClient;
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public Products getProducts() throws URISyntaxException {
        final String path = FAKE_STORE + "/products";
        return customTemplateClient.get(new URI(path), Products.class);
    }
}
```

When I am trying to run the the application (other project), I am getting below error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.restteplatestarterdemo.controller.ProductController required a bean of type 'com.example.http.client.CustomTemplateClient' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.http.client.CustomTemplateClient' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why the bean is not getting created?

Comment: `resources/META-INF/spring.factories` - that approach became deprecated in spring-boot v2.7 and was completely removed in v3, now you need to define autoconfiguration classes in `resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` file

Comment: yes, now it is working. I was also checking the spring-Kafka project. There is an aot.factories file under resources/META-INF/spring. what is this for?

Comment: `aot.factories` is for integrating with Spring Framework's support for ahead-of-time processing and GraalVM. You're unlikely to need to use it unless you start using some advanced or unusual configuration.